# Supportive android api levels for NDK,GLES20,VBO. Froyo devices that don't support ARM

Tags: android-ndk, arm, opengl-es-2.0, vbo, android-2.2-froyo

For what I know if you use NDK such api levels are supported:

ARM, ARM-NEON   - Android 1.5 (**API Level 3**) and higher
x86 - Android 2.3 (**API Level 9**) and higher
MIPS    - Android 2.3 (**API Level 9**) and higher

GLES20 supports Android 2.0 (**API Level 5**) and higher

VBO supports from Android 2.3 (**API Level 9**) and higher.
VBO would be supported from  **API Level 5** but OpenGL ES bindings are broken on Froyo (2.2), and incomplete/unavailable in earlier versions. There is workaround by using your own Java Native Interface (JNI) library to interface with the native OpenGL ES system libraries. 
One of open source such libraries I found is from guys who created *libgdx*.

it uses:

> /libs/armeabi/libandroidgl20.so /libs/armeabi-v7a/libandroidgl20.so
>   src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidGL20.java
>   src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/GL20.java
>   src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/GLCommon.java

I want that my application would use NDK ARM, GLES20,VBO's and would be supported from  android api level 5 and higher.

If I would use the workaround for the VBO's it would seem to be everything ok, but those libraries wouldn't work on platforms that do not run on ARM. So my question is ,  are there many Eclair/Froyo devices that don't support ARM? Maybe someone could provide any sort of list of them? And a suggestion of similar workaround libraries?

Comment: FWIW, there are very few Eclair devices still in use.  Froyo is currently at 1.1%.  http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=ausdroid.net